# Associate activerecord model on to a factorygirl factory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, factory-bot

Here are the basics of what I'm trying to do. I have a FactoryGirl factory `Message` and an ActiveRecord model `Channel`. During the build process and startup of a new rails test instance multiple `Channels` are created and saved to the database. The values used to create these channels are populated from a file in the repo. These values are used through out both controllers and views so simulating this process with FactoryGirl factories would be difficult. As far as I'm aware that would border on fixture data. I want to create a FactoryGirl associate on the `Message` factory to the `Channel` model. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is creating the `message` instances from the Message factory and doing this:

```
channel.messages << message
```

So pushing the message instance in to the channel instance. This works great. Calling message.destroy removes the association. I couldn't do this within factory girl but this work around should work.